# Is it possible or correct to use the inherent database errors to validate data type and lenghts?

Tags: php, mysql

I caught myself validating data to make sure it matched the database's data types and lengths, before inserting it into the database. Since this is the only validation I need, I was wondering if this isn't redundant, since the database already gives me errors if the data types or lengths don't match.

Is it possible or correct to take advantage of those errors? How can I go about using them, instead of making my own validations? Another advantage I see is that, if it's the database giving an error, the validations become more generic, because I wouldn't have to write validation code for each and every table.

For example, using MySQL and PHP Data Objects (PDO):

```
public function validate() {
// Make sure there are no pre-existing errors
...check errors...
// Make sure all the object's fields are set
...check that all the object's fields are set...
// Make sure all the object's fields are database-compatible
...check that all those fields are the correct type and length for the database...
}
```

Appreciate any enlightenment :)

Comment: Database errors are database specific. Your app should interpret it in a app specific way. Duplicate emails in user table is a duplicate key error in db. But in you app, its "This email is not available". In the database it was error. But in your app it becomes a simple information.

Comment: i think it is good to validate your data from your application before sending to database.or if your application usage goes high, your database will become a validator instead of its actual purpose (data storage)